# I accidently deleted database folder from MySQL Server

Tags: mysql, restore

I have a MYSQL server and I had created some database on it. Accidently, I deleted one database folder from the directory.

I have copy of that database folder saved as backup.

I stopped the server and pasted the database folder in it. After starting the server I notice I can see the database but am unable to run Query on it.

**Error msg - Table does not exist with error code: 1146**

I didn't get, Server can see the database but unable to run query on it.

Please give me some method to restore the database properly on the server as I don't have ".SQL" file of it.

Comment: Can you confirm what files were deleted and if you are using separate files for each table. If there was a separate .ibd file for the missing table you can try to import the tablespace, but with InnoDB it is better to export the data and back it up, then to copy the files

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete and re-import the tablespace (assuming it's innodb). Have look at this article: https://blog.toadworld.com/2017/06/14/transportable-tablespaces-in-innodb.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link but my system OS is Windows and the reference link is for Linux. Do you have a solution which will work for Windows OS